# How to change value of input on click?

Tags: jquery, checkbox

I load content via ajax and want to change value of each checkbox if click of them. I try

```
function calculate(){
    if($('input[type=checkbox][checked]')) {
        $(this).attr({ 
            value: 1
        });
    } else {
        $(this).attr({ 
            value: 0
        });
    }
    calculatebbb();
}
```

and add to each input:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="a003" value="230073" onclick="calculate()">
```

but it doesn't check this elemnt, it chcked all elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works as you like

**HTML**

```
<input type="checkbox" name="a003" value="230073" onclick="calculate(this);">
```

**Javascript**

```
function calculate(checkbox){
    console.log($(checkbox));
    if($(checkbox).attr("checked")) {
        $(checkbox).val(1);
    } else {
        $(checkbox).val(0);
    }
    calculatebbb();
}
```

**Demo** http://jsfiddle.net/2hy4h/

What you did wrong:

`this` is not your input here. If you check with `console.log(this)`.

Also `input[type=checkbox][checked]` does not select your input, maybe use an id here.

You can set a value with `.val(1)`

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
...ajax call...
success: function(data) {
... append Your input elements to #myDiv ...
    $('#myDiv input').bind('click', function(){
        var that = $(this);
        if( that.is(':checked') ) {
            that.val(1)
            } else {
        that.val(0)
        }
        calculatebbb();
    });
},
...
```

Comment: But where i can put this function if i load input elements via ajax and need toapply this clicked function only fo inputs in some div? (not in all document)

Answer (score 1):

Try sorted one

```
if($('input[type=checkbox]')bind('click', function(){  

    $(this).attr('checked', !$(this).attr('checked')); 

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
$(this).attr({ 
  value: 1
});
```

try

```
$(this).val(1);
```

**// EDIT**: The other mistake is that you use `this` in function `calculate`. Here `this` refers to the function - not the input. You should use a jQuery like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('input').click(function() {
    // do your things with this
  });
});
```

instead of defining click handler in HTML.

Answer (score 0):

IN this case
should be like this.
 $(this).val('value u wan to put');

if u dun wan to use jquery
document.getElementById('id').value = xxx;
but in this case u nid to put id ur html element.

Answer (score 0):

Change your code to this:

```
function calculate(obj) {
    obj.value = obj.checked + 0;
    calculatebbb();
}
```

And HTML:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="a003" value="230073" onclick="calculate(this)">
```

So if checked value will become 1, and 0 if unchecked.