# Counting elements doesn't work

Tags: javascript, jquery, counting

I have a table and want to calculate each element like:

```
calc-this-cost * calc-this-cost(value of checkbox) = calc-this-total
```

Then summ all `calc-this-cost` and put it to totalcost div.
This is table:

```
  <td class="params2">
    <table id="calc-params">
    <tr>
    <td>aaa</td><td class="calc-this-cost">159964</td><td class="calc-this-count">
    <input type="checkbox" name="a002" value="0" onclick="calculate(this);" />
    </td><td class="calc-this-total">0</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>bbb</td><td class="calc-this-cost">230073</td><td class="calc-this-count">
    <input type="checkbox" name="a003" value="0" onclick="calculate(this);" />
    </td><td class="calc-this-total">0</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>ccc</td><td class="calc-this-cost">159964</td><td class="calc-this-count">
    <input type="checkbox" name="a004" value="1" onclick="calculate(this);" />
    </td><td class="calc-this-total">0</td>
    </tr>
    ........
    </table>
    .......
    </td>
<div id="calc-total-price">TOTAL COST:&nbsp;&nbsp;<span>0</span></div>
```

My script (in function calculate)

```
var totalcost=0;
    $('.params2 tr').each(function(){
        var count=parseFloat($('input[type=checkbox]',$(this)).attr('value'));
        var price=parseFloat($('.calc-this-cost',$(this)).text().replace(" ",""));
        $('.calc-this-total',$(this)).html(count*price);
        totalcost+=parseFloat($('.calc-this-cost',$(this)).text());
    });
    $('#calc-total-price span').html(totalcost);
```

Counting each element and put result to calc-this-cost - work perfect.

But totalcost result NaN. Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`console.log()` will solve all your problems:

```
$('.params2 tr').each(function(){
    var count=parseFloat($('input[type=checkbox]',$(this)).attr('value'));
    var price=parseFloat($('.calc-this-cost',$(this)).text().replace(" ",""));
    $('.calc-this-total',$(this)).html(count*price);
    totalcost+=parseFloat($('.calc-this-cost',$(this)).text());
    console.log(count, price, totalcost)
});
```

Add more logging where every you don't understand something. Didn't I just [tell you](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9189363/956397) to use logging? :)

Answer (score 2):

1. [general] don't parseFloat() more than you need to
2. [general] move repeating code to functions
3. [jQuery] use .find() over context and cache nodes ($row)
4. [general] look at how String.replace() works
5. [general] look at Number.toFixed() for displaying floats

example

```
var totalcost = 0,
    toFloat = function(value) {
        // remove all whitespace
        // note that replace(" ", '') only replaces the first _space_ found!
        value = (value + "").replace(/\s+/g, '');
        value = parseFloat(value || "0", 10);
        return !isNaN(value) ? value : 0;
    };

$('.params2 tr').each( function() {
    var $row = $(this),
        count = toFloat($row.find('.calc-this-count input').val()), 
        price = toFloat($row.find('.calc-this-cost').text()),
        total = count * price;

    $row.find('calc-this-total').text(total.toFixed(2));
    totalcost += total;
});

$('#calc-total-price span').text(totalcost.toFixed(2));
```